# JBOSS 5.0.0.GA Startup Exception: org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Failed to register driver for: SQLServerDriver

Tags: jboss5.x, startup-error

I am having following exceptions while starting JBoss Server version 5.0.0.GA from eclipse indigo IDE:

```
12:10:21,394 WARN  [JBossManagedConnectionPool] Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null
org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Failed to register driver for: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver; - nested throwable: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver from BaseClassLoader@64b5ab{VFSClassLoaderPolicy@1d30b80{name=vfsfile:/D:/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/deploy/quartz-service.xml domain=ClassLoaderDomain@18adae2{name=DefaultDomain parentPolicy=BEFORE parent=org.jboss.system.NoAnnotationURLClassLoader@df8ff1} roots=[MemoryContextHandler@9967091[path= context=vfsmemory://5c4o3p4z-92x3ci-h9qonarz-1-h9qonw1u-1a real=vfsmemory://5c4o3p4z-92x3ci-h9qonarz-1-h9qonw1u-1a]]  delegates=null exported=[] <IMPORT-ALL>NON_EMPTY}}))
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:225)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:195)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:611)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:257)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool$BasePool.getConnection(JBossManagedConnectionPool.java:607)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.getManagedConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:404)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.getManagedConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:381)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:496)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2$ConnectionManagerProxy.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:941)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:89)
    at org.quartz.utils.JNDIConnectionProvider.getConnection(JNDIConnectionProvider.java:160)
    at org.quartz.utils.DBConnectionManager.getConnection(DBConnectionManager.java:112)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:686)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.getNonManagedTXConnection(JobStoreTX.java:72)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.doCheckin(JobStoreSupport.java:3167)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.manage(JobStoreSupport.java:3811)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.run(JobStoreSupport.java:3847)
Caused by: org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Failed to register driver for: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver; - nested throwable: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver from BaseClassLoader@64b5ab{VFSClassLoaderPolicy@1d30b80{name=vfsfile:/D:/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/deploy/quartz-service.xml domain=ClassLoaderDomain@18adae2{name=DefaultDomain parentPolicy=BEFORE parent=org.jboss.system.NoAnnotationURLClassLoader@df8ff1} roots=[MemoryContextHandler@9967091[path= context=vfsmemory://5c4o3p4z-92x3ci-h9qonarz-1-h9qonw1u-1a real=vfsmemory://5c4o3p4z-92x3ci-h9qonarz-1-h9qonw1u-1a]]  delegates=null exported=[] <IMPORT-ALL>NON_EMPTY}})
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getDriver(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:489)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:206)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver from BaseClassLoader@64b5ab{VFSClassLoaderPolicy@1d30b80{name=vfsfile:/D:/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/deploy/quartz-service.xml domain=ClassLoaderDomain@18adae2{name=DefaultDomain parentPolicy=BEFORE parent=org.jboss.system.NoAnnotationURLClassLoader@df8ff1} roots=[MemoryContextHandler@9967091[path= context=vfsmemory://5c4o3p4z-92x3ci-h9qonarz-1-h9qonw1u-1a real=vfsmemory://5c4o3p4z-92x3ci-h9qonarz-1-h9qonw1u-1a]]  delegates=null exported=[] <IMPORT-ALL>NON_EMPTY}}
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:385)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getDriver(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:474)
    ... 17 more
12:10:21,497 WARN  [JBossManagedConnectionPool] Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null
org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Failed to register driver for: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver; - nested throwable: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver from BaseClassLoader@64b5ab{VFSClassLoaderPolicy@1d30b80{name=vfsfile:/D:/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/deploy/quartz-service.xml domain=ClassLoaderDomain@18adae2{name=DefaultDomain parentPolicy=BEFORE parent=org.jboss.system.NoAnnotationURLClassLoader@df8ff1} roots=[MemoryContextHandler@9967091[path= context=vfsmemory://5c4o3p4z-92x3ci-h9qonarz-1-h9qonw1u-1a real=vfsmemory://5c4o3p4z-92x3ci-h9qonarz-1-h9qonw1u-1a]]  delegates=null exported=[] <IMPORT-ALL>NON_EMPTY}}))
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:225)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:195)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:611)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:257)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool$BasePool.getConnection(JBossManagedConnectionPool.java:607)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.getManagedConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:404)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.getManagedConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:381)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:496)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2$ConnectionManagerProxy.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:941)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:89)
    at org.quartz.utils.JNDIConnectionProvider.getConnection(JNDIConnectionProvider.java:160)
    at org.quartz.utils.DBConnectionManager.getConnection(DBConnectionManager.java:112)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:686)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.getNonManagedTXConnection(JobStoreTX.java:72)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.doCheckin(JobStoreSupport.java:3167)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.manage(JobStoreSupport.java:3811)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.run(JobStoreSupport.java:3847)
Caused by: org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Failed to register driver for: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver; - nested throwable: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver from BaseClassLoader@64b5ab{VFSClassLoaderPolicy@1d30b80{name=vfsfile:/D:/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/deploy/quartz-service.xml domain=ClassLoaderDomain@18adae2{name=DefaultDomain parentPolicy=BEFORE parent=org.jboss.system.NoAnnotationURLClassLoader@df8ff1} roots=[MemoryContextHandler@9967091[path= context=vfsmemory://5c4o3p4z-92x3ci-h9qonarz-1-h9qonw1u-1a real=vfsmemory://5c4o3p4z-92x3ci-h9qonarz-1-h9qonw1u-1a]]  delegates=null exported=[] <IMPORT-ALL>NON_EMPTY}})
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getDriver(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:489)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:206)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver from BaseClassLoader@64b5ab{VFSClassLoaderPolicy@1d30b80{name=vfsfile:/D:/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/deploy/quartz-service.xml domain=ClassLoaderDomain@18adae2{name=DefaultDomain parentPolicy=BEFORE parent=org.jboss.system.NoAnnotationURLClassLoader@df8ff1} roots=[MemoryContextHandler@9967091[path= context=vfsmemory://5c4o3p4z-92x3ci-h9qonarz-1-h9qonw1u-1a real=vfsmemory://5c4o3p4z-92x3ci-h9qonarz-1-h9qonw1u-1a]]  delegates=null exported=[] <IMPORT-ALL>NON_EMPTY}}
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:385)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getDriver(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:474)
    ... 17 more
12:10:21,598 WARN  [JBossManagedConnectionPool] Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null
org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Failed to register driver for: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver; - nested throwable: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver from BaseClassLoader@64b5ab{VFSClassLoaderPolicy@1d30b80{name=vfsfile:/D:/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/deploy/quartz-service.xml domain=ClassLoaderDomain@18adae2{name=DefaultDomain parentPolicy=BEFORE parent=org.jboss.system.NoAnnotationURLClassLoader@df8ff1} roots=[MemoryContextHandler@9967091[path= context=vfsmemory://5c4o3p4z-92x3ci-h9qonarz-1-h9qonw1u-1a real=vfsmemory://5c4o3p4z-92x3ci-h9qonarz-1-h9qonw1u-1a]]  delegates=null exported=[] <IMPORT-ALL>NON_EMPTY}}))
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:225)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:195)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:611)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:257)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool$BasePool.getConnection(JBossManagedConnectionPool.java:607)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.getManagedConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:404)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.getManagedConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:381)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:496)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2$ConnectionManagerProxy.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:941)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:89)
    at org.quartz.utils.JNDIConnectionProvider.getConnection(JNDIConnectionProvider.java:160)
    at org.quartz.utils.DBConnectionManager.getConnection(DBConnectionManager.java:112)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:686)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.getNonManagedTXConnection(JobStoreTX.java:72)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.doCheckin(JobStoreSupport.java:3167)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.manage(JobStoreSupport.java:3811)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.run(JobStoreSupport.java:3847)
Caused by: org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Failed to register driver for: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver; - nested throwable: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver from BaseClassLoader@64b5ab{VFSClassLoaderPolicy@1d30b80{name=vfsfile:/D:/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/deploy/quartz-service.xml domain=ClassLoaderDomain@18adae2{name=DefaultDomain parentPolicy=BEFORE parent=org.jboss.system.NoAnnotationURLClassLoader@df8ff1} roots=[MemoryContextHandler@9967091[path= context=vfsmemory://5c4o3p4z-92x3ci-h9qonarz-1-h9qonw1u-1a real=vfsmemory://5c4o3p4z-92x3ci-h9qonarz-1-h9qonw1u-1a]]  delegates=null exported=[] <IMPORT-ALL>NON_EMPTY}})
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getDriver(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:489)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:206)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver from BaseClassLoader@64b5ab{VFSClassLoaderPolicy@1d30b80{name=vfsfile:/D:/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/deploy/quartz-service.xml domain=ClassLoaderDomain@18adae2{name=DefaultDomain parentPolicy=BEFORE parent=org.jboss.system.NoAnnotationURLClassLoader@df8ff1} roots=[MemoryContextHandler@9967091[path= context=vfsmemory://5c4o3p4z-92x3ci-h9qonarz-1-h9qonw1u-1a real=vfsmemory://5c4o3p4z-92x3ci-h9qonarz-1-h9qonw1u-1a]]  delegates=null exported=[] <IMPORT-ALL>NON_EMPTY}}
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:385)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getDriver(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:474)
    ... 17 more
```

But it is working fine when I run the debug.bat outside eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see the exception at the very end

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver
```

Check your classpath, look like its not able to find the class.

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: Thanks, I found the issue. In my classpath, the driver was there but it wasn't compatible with the deployed WAR on JBOSS.